# What is the difference between @ComponentScans and @ComponentScan?

Tags: java, spring

I see that we have `@org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans` and `@org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan`.

1. How do we use `@ComponentScans()` ?
2. How is `@ComponentScans()` different from `@ComponentScan({"com.org.abc", "com.org.xyz"})`

Comment: ComponentScans can contain many nested ComponentScan, right? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScans.html

Comment: `@ComponentScans({@ComponentScan("com.org.abc"), @ComponentScan("com.org.xyz")})` is equivalent to your example . In the code of the `ComponentScans` annotation, there is nothing more than `ComponentScan[] value();`

Comment: If you are using Java 8 you don't ever need to use `ComponentScans`. It's just a workaround for limitations of Java < 8 when having repeated annotations. Do not use it. Note that this was actually a pattern so there is plenty of annotations that have a plural version used in that way, but they can be safely ignored in Java8+ where you can simply repeat the annotations

Comment: Thanks everyone.. Its clear that I don't have to use `@ComponentScans()`  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Spring can automatically scan a package for beans if component
>   scanning is enabled.
>
> `@ComponentScan` configures which packages to scan for classes with
>   annotation configuration. We can specify the base package names
>   directly with one of the basePackages or value arguments (value is an
>   alias for basePackages)
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.baeldung.annotations")
> class VehicleFactoryConfig {}
> ```
>
> Also, we can point to classes in the base packages with the
>   `basePackageClasses` argument:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = VehicleFactoryConfig.class)
> class VehicleFactoryConfig {}
> ```
>
> Both arguments are arrays so that we can provide multiple packages for
>   each.
>
> If no argument is specified, the scanning happens from the same
>   package where the `@ComponentScan` annotated class is present.
>
> @ComponentScan leverages the Java 8 repeating annotations feature,
>   which means we can mark a class with it multiple times:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.baeldung.annotations")
> @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = VehicleFactoryConfig.class)
> class VehicleFactoryConfig {}
> ```
>
> Alternatively, we can use `@ComponentScans` to specify multiple
>   `@ComponentScan` configurations:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @ComponentScans({ 
>     @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.baeldung.annotations"), 
>     @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = VehicleFactoryConfig.class)
> })
> class VehicleFactoryConfig {}
> ```

You can found more [Spring Bean Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-annotations)

Comment: So is there any advantage in using `ComponentScans`? Or is it just for readability?

Comment: `ComponentScans` that act as a container annotation that aggregates several `ComponentScan` annotations. So I think we no need to care it, just done it by your way.

Comment: As @Giacomo said "If you are using Java 8 you don't ever need to use `@ComponentScans()`. It's just a workaround for limitations of Java < 8 when having repeated annotations. Do not use it. "

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at documentation:

> [ComponentScans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScans.html) Container annotation that aggregates several
>   ComponentScan annotations.
>
> [ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) Configures component scanning directives for use
>   with @Configuration classes.